# Microsoft LifeCam Studio capable of preview and capture of a picture separately?

Tags: webcam, resolution, preview, snapshot

I currently have an application that can show a video preview stream and take a picture from that stream.  The problem is the app needs to run on low end machines (ie. nettops), and when the video preview stream is set to a high resoultion, it kills the framerates.  So my questions are:

1. Can the Lifecam preview the stream at a low resolution, but snap pictures at a higher resolution (via the Preview pin?)?
2. By doing so, will it actually increase performance?  The preview should run buttery smooth (30fps) at 320x240 but take snapshots at 1080p.
3. How will all the auto adjustments be affected by this?  Will the auto adjustments apply when the snapshot is taken?
4. Will there be a significant lag when taking the picture?

I'm not too familiar with DirectShow and the 3rd party control i'm using doesn't seem to support this mode.  After some reading, i can't tell definitively whether or not the LifeCam Studio is capable of this.  Testing with the AForge Snapshot Maker, it wasn't able to set snapshot resolution, which suggests that the Lifecam isn't capable of this.  But of course, it could just be a problem with the software.  I just need to know of the Lifecams capablilities before investing the time to implement the functionality.  I figured someone already went through the trouble of figuring this out and would like to share their findings.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we have different resolutions for Preview and Capture of the same DirectShow graph?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717662/can-we-have-different-resolutions-for-preview-and-capture-of-the-same-directshow)

Answer (score 0):

Most, or all, devices don't allow different resolutions for capture and preview in DirectShow. See [Can we have different resolutions for Preview and Capture of the same DirectShow graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717662/can-we-have-different-resolutions-for-preview-and-capture-of-the-same-directshow) for similar discussion.

I believe Microsoft LifeCam Studio captures high res JPEG, so it is technically possible to take it off the pipeline in compressed form without performance overhead and decompress into subsampled image (IJG code offers this option). This is going to be performance friendly.